# too long and would be truncated in CONCAT with Data masking policy

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I implemented Data masking policy on two view columns which are First_Name and Last_Name in the Customer table with sha2(Val) based on the current role.  Ex. alter view .<SCHEMA_NAME>.<TABLE_NAE> modify
column <COLUMN_NAME> set masking policy public.pii_allowed;
When executing view definition by concatenating both columns it's running fine but giving an error with a view.
That is "String 689z3z73z8z32zz46z24zz916z15zzz6z4z45z26zz887zzz98765432zz2312z5 yy3y9y24y61yy0y910y63y6yy384y277y670y283746y2y2y960y25y6y85yy03 is too long and would be truncated in 'CONCAT'". The result value length is 129 including space.

I tryied to write case statement to avoid the to print the value. Ex. case when length(First_name||''||Last_name) > 64 THEN First_Name esle lenght(First_name||''||Last_name) end Name. But till it is giving error with above message with Complex views.

Please suggest resolving this error.

Comment: Can you post your view definition please?

Comment: Can you also include the CREATE MASKING POLICY statement, please?